# Binding multiple list boxes in TK inter with pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am new to Tkinter GUI, and trying to achieve following

I've dataframe df

```
AccountName             Group1              Group2              Group3

Cost                    Global          Global              Global
Cost                    Global          Global              Global
Cost                    Global          Global              Global
Cost                    Region          Total Asia          Asia
Cost                    Region          Asia                Singapore
Cost                    Region          Asia                Indonesia
```

I've Three list boxes in TK frame with unique values and an additional text items "Select ALL" in each list boxes

```
Group1              Group2              Group3

Global              Global              Global
Region              Total Asia          Asia
Select All          Asia                Singapore
                    Select All          Indonesia
                                        Select All
```

I want to bind these list boxes together in a way that if I select a value in Group1 then only related values should appear in Group2 and Group3. Similarly, if I select a value in Group2 then only related value should appear in Group3.
In addition, if I select 'Select ALL' then other list boxes should show all values.

**Expected Output**

Example1: If Group1 selection is Region

```
Group1              Group2           Group3
Region              Total Asia          Asia
                    Asia              Singapore
                    Select ALL        Indonesia
                                      Select ALL
```

Example2: If Group1 selection is Select ALL

```
Group1              Group2          Group3
Select ALL          Global          Global
                    Total Asia      Asia
                    Asia            Singapore
                    Select ALL      Indonesia
                                    Select ALL
```

Example 3: If Group1 Selection is Region and Group2 Selection is Asia

```
Group1              Group2          Group3
Region              Asia           Singapore
                                   Indonesia
                                   Select ALL
```

**Coding**
I've done coding to assign values to list box through dataframe but not sure how to proceed further

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
import DataImport as dI

df = dI.import_Data()

def listing(data):
  a = []
  for i in data:
    if i not in a:
      a.append(i)
  return a

G1 = listing(df["Groupby_L1"].tolist())
G1.append(" Select ALL")
G2 = listing(df["Groupby_L2"].tolist())
G2.append("Select ALL")
G3 = listing(df["Groupby_L3"].tolist())
G3.append("Select ALL")

def listboxs(listbox, data):
  i = 0
  for widget in data:
    listbox.insert(i, widget)
    i = i + 1

#in tk frame I am using follwing code

Group1 = Label(frame1)
Group1.config(text='Groupby_L1')
Group1.grid(column='1', ipadx='10', padx='5', pady='30', row='1')
Group1_Data = Listbox(frame1, selectmode=MULTIPLE)
Group1_Data.config(height=3, width=20)
listboxs(Group1_Data, G1)
Group1_Data.grid(column='2', row='1')

Group2 = Label(frame1)
Group2.config(text='Groupby_L2')
Group2.grid(column='15', padx='60', row='0')
Group2_Data = Listbox(frame1, selectmode=MULTIPLE)
Group2_Data.config(height=3, width=20)
listboxs(Group2_Data, G2)
Group2_Data.grid(column='20', row='0')

Group3 = Label(frame1)
Group3.config(text='Groupby_L3')
Group3.grid(column='15', padx='60', row='1')
Group3_Data = Listbox(frame1, selectmode=MULTIPLE)
Group3_Data.config(height=3, width=20)
listboxs(Group3_Data, G3)
Group3_Data.grid(column='20', row='1')
```

Comment: What is the problem now.

Comment: problem is basically how to link group1 list box with group2 and group3 list box so that group2 and 3 list box should show items based on selection of Group1 list box

Comment: listbox has a virtual bind called `<<ListboxSelect>>`, you could use that. Along with some filters.

Comment: thanks, so currently I am loading each columns ( group1/2/3) from data frame to 3 list boxes separately. Does that mean if I'll load list to 1st group1 list box only and use <<ListboxSelect>>  for other list boxes, then other list boxes will show only connected results?

Comment: Not really, you have to link them manually. Using `insert()` and `delete()`.